24.04 sharing can not be activated & remote desktop not visible
I have Ubuntu 24.04 installed on a Raspberry Pi 5. Settings Menu. Sharing can not be activated. Remote desktop not visible. Un/installed the Gnome remote desktop like in an other topic mentioned, but it doesn't change anything. I would like to use rdp and filesharing outside the house network, for example in another country. I was a Mac user server (it broke down after 13 years). I was able to do that. I hope the Raspberry Pi can do that too.

